# Increasing Accuracy of Image Classification Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to use do image classification on two different classes using the pre-trained Inception V3 model. I have a data set of around 1400 images which are roughly balanced. When I run my program I get results that are off at the first couple epochs. Is this normal when training the model?

```
epochs =  175

batch_size = 64

#include_top = false to accomodate new classes 
base_model = keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        weights ='imagenet',
        include_top=False, 
        input_shape = (img_width,img_height,3))

#Classifier Model ontop of Convolutional Model
model_top = keras.models.Sequential()
model_top.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:], data_format=None)),
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(350,activation='relu'))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))
model_top.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid'))
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = model_top(base_model.output))

#freeze the convolutional layers of InceptionV3
for layer in model.layers[:30]:
layer.trainable = False

#Compiling model using Adam Optimizer 
model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(
                    lr=0.000001,
                    beta_1=0.9,
                    beta_2=0.999,
                    epsilon=1e-08),
                    loss='binary_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image]

With my current parameters I only get an accuracy of 89% with a test loss of 0.3 when testing on a separated set of images. Do I need to add more layers to my model to increase this accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code...

To start with, your way to build `model_top` is quite unconventional (and IMHO quite messy as well); in such cases, the [documentation examples](https://keras.io/applications/#usage-examples-for-image-classification-models) are your best friend. So, start with replacing your `model_top` part with:

```
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(350, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

Notice that I have not changed your parameters of choice - you could certainly experiment with more units in the dense layer (the example in the docs uses 1024)...

Second, it is not clear why you choose to freeze only 30 layers of the InceptionV3, which has no less than 311 layers:

```
len(base_model.layers)
# 311
```

So, replace also this part with

```
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Third, your learning rate seems way too small; the Adam optimizer is supposed to work well enough out of the box with its default parameters, so I also suggest to compile your model simply as

```
model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                    loss='binary_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
```